# com.google.common.cache.Cache class not found error

Tags: java, servlets, guava, classnotfoundexception

I am using Guava 14.0 jar and following is my code

```
package org.user.module.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder;
import com.google.common.cache.Cache;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class test
 */
@WebServlet("/test")
public class test extends HttpServlet  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Cache<String, Integer> map;

    public test() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void init() throws ServletException
    {
        map=CacheBuilder.newBuilder().
                maximumSize(100).
                expireAfterAccess(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES).
                build();

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        String p=request.getParameter("v");
        Integer a=map.getIfPresent(p);
        if(a==null){
            map.put(p, 1);
            out.println("Putting The Integer:"+a);
        }
        else{
            map.put(p,a++);
            out.println("A is already present and the value is:"+a);
        }

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request,response);
    }

}
```

Error:

> SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet org.user.module.test.test
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.cache.Cache   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
>     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2317)     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1762)    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.populateAnnotationsCache(DefaultInstanceManager.java:276)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:143)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:125)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1136)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:857)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

downloaded jar from here [Downlaod Link](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/Release14)
Link to my project folder(Project name:test2) [LINK](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_pKO9JFqkPsX042OEN1ZnVDa1U/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: where have you put the JAR file?

Comment: I have right clicked the project->Configure Build Path->add Library->and selected guava. Its in the lib folder inside project. Look at the link I edited

Comment: Your lib folder should be in `/WebContent/WEB-INF` folder. Currently you are having it under Java Resources. Remove it from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obvious answer is that; 
The Google guava jar is not found from the classpath dictated by the application server. The jar should be present in either **WEB-INF/classes** or **WEB-INF/lib**. Apache Tomcat also loads common classes from **$CATALINA_HOME/lib** folder.

Comment: Jars don't go in /classes.  Classes do.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen you are absolutely correct. It's good to drive the consistency for example. in case of running the app in debug mode,  hot-swap:ing or overriding classes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the jar's name! Poorly documented dependencies lead to complications when trying to import a package :p